# Страница с параметрами в Wordpress на ЧПУ

Tags: mod_rewrite, wordpress, чпу

Привет.

Хочу, чтобы для определённой страницы Wordpress можно было передавать параметры и перехватывать их через плагин (без использования get параметров в адресной строке).

Например: http://domain.com/page/argument

Как можно это сделать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} argument=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1%1? [R=301, L]
```

Полный конфиг для WP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} argument=(\w+)$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1%1? [R=301, L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

URL для примера: http://domain.com/page/?argument=1

[Проверить можно здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

`RewriteBase /` можно убрать, ибо слэш проставлен в самом правиле `/$1%1?`.

Comment: я просто думал, что это можно сделать через встроенные функции:
add_rewrite_rule
add_rewrite_tag

Но они на отрез отказываются работать как документированы, либо я не понимаю вселенную Wordpress.

Comment: И вы, наверное, меня недопоняли:

В оригинале я имею адрес: http://domain.com/page/?argument=value

И хотел бы получить тот же результат, но по вот такому адресу: http://domain.com/page/value

Comment: @nddd Всё до безобразия просто. Замените `[0-9]` на `\w` (буквенные и цифровые символы, а также underscore-символ `_`). Почитайте про [RegExp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Исправил ответ.

Если необходимо дополнить иными правилами/исправить существующее, пишите, будем думать.

Comment: Правильный ответ:
На action -> "init" необходимо добавить функцию в теле которой будет:

add_rewrite_tag("%arg%", "([^&]+)");
add_rewrite_rule("page/([^/]*)?$", 'index.php?pagename=page&arg=$matches[1]', 'top');
flush_rewrite_rules();

Comment: @nddd Этот приём для "полотёров". Вы хоть понимаете, что все эти правила означают?

Comment: примерно понимаю)

Comment: @nddd Я не знаю, что там в "кишках" у WP, но предполагаю add_rewrite_rule делает редирект средствами php. Средствами сервера быстрее. Да, и выставите где-нибудь в `add_rewrite_rule`, чтобы редирект был [перманентный `301`](http://www.kass.ws/2007/09/13/301-redirect-rukovodstvo-po-pravilnoy-seo-ekspluatatsii/).